# How to create seperate login system for user and service provider in django

Tags: django, authentication

I have this fully functional `user auth system`

User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']
```

User login view .I'm using `JWT` tokens stored in cookies.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def LoginView(request):
    email = request.data['email']
    password = request.data['password']
    user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
    if user is None:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')
    if not user.check_password(password):
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')
    payload = {
            'id': user.id,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }
    token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256') 
    response = Response()
    response.data = {
            'jwt': token
        }
    return response
```

In my `React` front-end i use `react-auth-kit` to check if the user if logged-in, to be able to access `UserProfile.jsx` component which is private as shown bellow.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ Component }) => {
    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
    const auth = isAuthenticated();
    return auth ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
  };

<Router>
          <NavBar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            <Route
              path="/profile"
              element={<PrivateRoute Component={UserProfile} />}
            />
          <Footer />
        </Router>
```

The `Login.jsx` component has a simple `axios` request to get data from backend.

```
axios
      .post(
        "/api/login",
        {
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
        },
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
```

Now my problem. I have another separate django modal for `Service providers`.

```
class provider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','email','password']
    
    def __str__(self):
          return (self.name)
```

The service provider has access to components that normal user doesn't have access to (like `Dashboard.jsx`.

How can implement the login for both models together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options. You might want to refactor your models to be something like:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_provider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and make sure that all views related to service providers operate only if the logged in user has `is_provider=True`.